# Tunneling all TCP and UDP traffic through a Server?

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunnel, tunneling, socks

On a Linux or Windows system, how would it be possible to tunnel all TCP/UDP packets through a thirdparty server? What would one use, does it work with SOCKS5, OpenVPN or SSH?

Comment: hi guys! thanks for the answers. as a first step i installed vpn on a remote root server, and on my local windows 7 desktop.
works all fine, connection over port udp/1194 is running, i can ping the other machine. but what i don't understand is now how do i setup my system to route all traffic through the vpn? thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh will give you probably simplest way of tunneling tcp traffic to know destination/port.

if you would like to tunnel traffic to any destination [tcp/udp/icmp... all ip traffic in general] - openvpn will do the trick.

Comment: i finished setting it up, and it works but now i don't know how to configure windows 7 in order to put all traffic through the openvpn? can you help me?

Comment: @lan - check redirect-gateway option of openvpn and run openvpngui with elevated privileges/as admin, otherwise it's unable to manipulate routing table under vista/7.

Comment: thx mate, I'll try that one!

Answer (score 3):

I use a socks 5 with [proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) I open a dynamic tunnel with putty and put everything through there with proxifier.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options available as you have identified in your question itself. It comes down to possibly the following factors as to one over the other:

- Availability of the technology across your target platforms (Windows, Linux, etc.)
- Your technical security requirements (encryption strength, known weaknesses, etc.)
- Your comfort level with the technology (easy vs. hard to install, come by, etc.)

Each one has some strengths and weaknesses when matched up against each other, but there are multiple choices to hopefully suit your needs.